# Electric field in a "concave" conductor

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I am aware that the electrons are  distributed across charged conductor surface so that the areas with smaller radius of curvature have more charge per surface area. But what happens when the conductor is concave, as displayed on the picture..

[image]

My idea is that the charge would accumulate at A and B parts and then those electrons would  force any electrons located on AC and AB towards C. Is this correct?

Comment: For a spherical surface the electric field **inside would be zero**. But for an arbitrary surface there would be areas with zero field and areas with non-zero field. One would have to use gauss law and decompose the surface.